# Change last digit of a number to 0 in excel 2010

Tags: excel

I have an Excel 2010 sheet with prices of over 4500 products. I'm curious if it's possible to change the prices last digit to 0. Something like this:

```
'129'->'120'
'334'->'330'
'11'->'10'
```

It is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

=floor(A1,10)

[image]

Replace A1 with your first cell reference, then copy down to the last row of data. If you want, you can copy the results of the formula and paste special > values over the original data, but after that, there's no getting the original values back.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! Both methods worked just fine!

Answer (score 1):

Try using ROUNDOWN or up

```
=ROUNDDOWN(A1,-1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

This formula will also do what you need:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(TEXT(N4170,"00"),LEN(TEXT(N4170,"00"))-1)&"0")
```